# Makefile 42: recipe for target 'util.o' failed

Tags: compiling, c++, makefile

I am getting this error:

```
~/Distrib$ make all
/usr/bin/g++ -O3 util.cc -I/home/shah/Distrib
util.cc: In function 'into countLines(const char*)':
util:19:8: error: 'exit' was not declared in this scope
  exit(1);
        ^
Makefile:42: recipe for target 'util.o' failed
make: *** [util.o] Error 1
```

Basically I am trying to install a piece of tomographic software that I downloaded from [this webpage](https://people.earth.yale.edu/software/jun-korenaga)

I changed line number 5 in the Makefile to

```
Home = /home/shah
```

[image: Makefile changes]

Comment: Line 5 before any change was HOME = /Users/jon

Show I add the missing header with hashtag sign or without it. I added it the way you typed above in the Makefile and got the same error. Then I removed the hashtag at the beginning and it gave me following error
$ Makefile :2: No such file or directory
$ make: ***no rule to make target '<stdlib.h>'. Stop.

Comment: Different compilers sometimes allow implicit exit() declaration.  Just put `#include <cstdlib>` into the cc files that fail to compile.

Comment: @Shaw No, `#include <stdlib.h>` or `#include <cstdlib>` should goes to *.cc, not Makefile

Comment: Thanks Alvin and Zanna. You guys are awesome.
I included the #include <stdlib.h> in util.cc and other files,which solved the problem.

Comment: [Related on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956636/c-on-linux-not-recognizing-commands-like-exit-and-printf)

Comment: @abu_bua what version is your gcc? Why do you think it is a makefile error? Did you need to fix the makefile? It is good practice to include that header afaik...

Comment: gcc7.3, the Makefile is very old-fashioned -> see `makedepend` . No need to alter anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you try this example you will see that the exit function is defined in #include

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {
   printf("Start of the program....\n");

   printf("Exiting the program....\n");
   exit(0);

   printf("End of the program....\n");

   return(0);
}
```

The file util.cc, which gives error does not contain the inclusion of StdLib of C.
That's why the error.

The mistake was mentioned by [Zanna](https://askubuntu.com/users/527764/zanna) in the previous comment.
In any case, ask the author, as he did to compile it. Since the 2003 publication, it seems that it worked for him.